# JQuery Mobile error on Windows Phone 7 (using Zend)

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

I'm building a web app in jQuery Mobile, and I've tested it on IOS and Android with no difficulties.  WebOS has some rendering problems, but nothing major.  But when I tested the app with Windows Phone 7, everything broke.

The jQuery Mobile kitchen sink demo works fine-- I thought it might be something with the javascript on my end, so I removed all of it.  However, this didn't fix the problem.  Since WP7 has no error console to speak of, it's very hard to diagnose what's happening.

Here it is:
http://abolition.me/wp7.php

I dumped the headers into my Zend log after clicking the same link in Chrome and WP7, and here's what I got:

wp7:

```
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us
[HTTP_REFERER] => http://mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us/mobile#/mobile/tasks?filter=Open
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html, */*; q=0.01
[HTTP_UA_CPU] => x86
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0; Trident/3.1; IEMobile/7.0; Microsoft; XDeviceEmulator)
[HTTP_HOST] => mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us
[HTTP_COOKIE] => <censored>
[HTTP_VIA] => <censored>
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => <censored>
[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=259200
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server at mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us Port 80</address>

[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
[SERVER_NAME] => mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us
[SERVER_ADDR] => 50.56.102.225
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 50.84.91.226
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/kinita_branch/mobile.uwn.me/Website
[SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/kinita_branch/mobile.uwn.me/Website/index.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 46576
[REDIRECT_URL] => /viewtask/84
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /viewtask/84
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1307642025
```

and here it is from Chrome:

```
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[HTTP_HOST] => mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us
[HTTP_REFERER] => http://mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us/mobile
[HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html, */*; q=0.01
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8
[HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
[HTTP_COOKIE] => <censored>
[HTTP_VIA] => <censored>
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => <censored>
[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=259200
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server at mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us Port 80</address>

[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
[SERVER_NAME] => mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us
[SERVER_ADDR] => 50.56.102.225
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 50.84.91.226
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/kinita_branch/mobile.uwn.me/Website
[SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/kinita_branch/mobile.uwn.me/Website/index.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 47085
[REDIRECT_URL] => /mobile/viewtask/84
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /mobile/viewtask/84
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1307642163
```

The problem is that WP7 is omitting /mobile from its request.

Any thoughts?  Have you seen anything like this before?

It should be noted that if I visit the urls directly (i.e. `/mobile/viewtask/90`), it works.  The problem seems to involve the way jQM does navigation.

Thanks!

Link to JQM issue report:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1796

Edit:
It should be noted that I'm using the Zend framework.

Comment: Read the docs about links and ajax. I remember some problems with the `/` at the beginning. Change your links to more relative. You are linking from a page that is in `/mobile/` so you only need to link to `tasks?whatever..`

Comment: The trouble is, I'm using the Zend framework which uses mod_rewrite to circumvent Apache's natural directory structure.  I'm making modifications to an existing Zend app to work in a mobile environment, and I need to address root relative URLs to make the new interface compatibile with the existing backend.

Comment: what happens if you open `/#/mobile/tasks?filter=Open` ? Also - install debugBar for IE and see what are the adresses that JQM loads with AJAX and see what are the responses.

Comment: Other helpful read - bottom of this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html And as far as I remember using relative links is not a problem for mod_rewrite, so try relative paths if you didn't do it just being sure it won't work.

Comment: I tried adding a trailing slash and it didn't fix the problem.  And you're right about relative URLs working with Zend-- unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem either.  You can see the broken app at the link I edited above.

Comment: And just to clarify further-- the issue in each case was the same.  The first part of the root-relative URL (/mobile) is being omitted in the request header.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you try the current version of jQuery Mobile at github? There have been a lot of changes in the navigation component, maybe your problem is already solved.

Comment: Testbaudson- yes.  That works.  Answer the question and I'll rep you/give you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for future readers: Problem is fixed in recent builds. 
It should not be present in releases coming after alpha4.1

I think your urls should be

```
http://mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us/mobile/#viewtask/93
```

instead of

```
http://mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us/mobile#/mobile/viewtask/93
```

You don't change anything related to mod_rewrite, just the links.

So

```
<a href="/mobile/tasks?filter=Open">
```

would be replaced by

```
<a href="tasks?filter=Open">
```

etc.

Comment: The URLs are being dynamically generated by jQuery Mobile.  For instance, if I specify http://mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us/mobile/viewtask/93, jQuery Mobile converts that into http://mobile.kinitawp7.designitfor.us/mobile#/mobile/viewtask/93.

I went ahead and tried using the relative URL viewtask/93, but that didn't work either-- jQuery Mobile is still truncating the first subdirectory of the URL (requesting /viewtask/93 instead of /mobile/viewtask/93).

Comment: Any progress? I suppose this could be reported as a bug on github, but that won't fix the problem for some time at least. I recommend reading about wp7 support, it's still a new thing for JQM

Comment: They fixed it sometime in the last week!  I had filed a bug report, but someone closed it as invalid.  Luckily, looks like someone was already on it.  Thanks!